# jQuery fadeIn/Out crashing

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, user-experience

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to create a simple thumbnail fadeIn / fadeOut animation with text. The code is simple but when I hover multiple times, fast, it stops responding.

```
(function(){
    $('.boxcaption').css({'display': 'none'})
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(function(){  
         $(".cover", this).stop().fadeIn(160);
    }, function() {  
        $(".cover", this).stop().fadeOut(160);
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: FYI There is a missing ';' character after the css() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not using the parameters for stop(); which would be `true, true`.

The jQuery docs explain this very well.
[.stop() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

I made a fiddle demonstrating this.

[HoverFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYZjq/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `.show()` and `.hide()` ?

```
(function(){
    $('.boxcaption').css({'display': 'none'})
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(function(){  
         $(".cover", this).stop().hide().fadeIn(160);
    }, function() {  
        $(".cover", this).stop().show().fadeOut(160);
    }); 
})();
```

Or you can also reset the opacity property before:

```
(function(){
    $('.boxcaption').css({'display': 'none'})
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(function(){  
         $(".cover", this).stop().css("opacity","1").fadeIn(160);
    }, function() {  
        $(".cover", this).stop().css("opacity","0").fadeOut(160);
    });
})();
```

Comment: If it works for you please don't forget to accept my answer as the solution by clicking on the big green check sign! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

try to cache the objects, $(".cover", this) - this means jquery starts to search for this element when you hover the mouse; there is a lot of coding going on behind this selector;

Also try to remove .stop() from the first hover function

```
(function(){
    //save selectors in variables
    var l1 = $('some_selector'), l2= $('some_selector2');

    $('.boxcaption').css({'display': 'none'})
        l1.hover(function(){  
         $(".cover", this).fadeIn(160);
    }, function() {  
        l2.stop().fadeOut(160);
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: not sure this will help, but at least you'll have some improvements

Comment: Seems that just a simple stop(true, true) before the animation did the job but thanks